# How to get a list of all pdfs/documents in a device with flutter without using file_picker

Tags: android, flutter, dart, pdf, filepicker

I'm trying get a list of all documents in a device without breaking the illusion of being in my app like file picker does. I test with my physical device and it was working before but since I bought a better device using Android 11, I've been having issues.

This is what I did back then that worked. After getting permission errors for trying to access `/storage/emulated/0/Android`, I think there has been a permission update so I am now temporarily avoiding that folder manually but still I couldn't see any files until I added .mp4 to the allowed extensions and then it showed only my videos.

```
List<File> bookList = []; 
List<List<String>> bookPropertyList = [];

fetchBooks() async {
var rootPath = await ExternalPath.getExternalStorageDirectories();
var docPath = Directory(rootPath[0]);
var docassets = docPath.listSync(recursive: true, followLinks: true);
for (FileSystemEntity asset in docassets) {
  if (asset is File) {
    String name = basename(asset.path);
    if (name.endsWith('.pdf') ||
        name.endsWith('.PDF') ||
        name.endsWith('.txt') ||
        name.endsWith('.TXT') ||
        name.endsWith('.doc') ||
        name.endsWith('.DOC') ||
        name.endsWith('.docx') ||
        name.endsWith('.DOCX')) {
      String size = await getSize(asset.statSync().size, 1);
      int day = asset.statSync().modified.day;
      int month = asset.statSync().modified.month;
      int year = asset.statSync().modified.year;
      String date = '$day/$month/$year';

      List<String> docProperty = [name, size, date];
      bookPropertyList.add(docProperty);
      File? file = asset.absolute;
      bookList.add(file);
    }
  }
}
}
```

Is there a reason why it wouldn't show my files?

And is there a better way to get the files without leaving the app? Perhaps a light package I could use.

Comment: On an Android 11+ device an app can see only its own files and some public media files. The times they are a changing.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you @blackapps . Is there a way people go about it now? I've tried photo manager package cos I've used it in the past but it only shows my images, audios and videos. Is file picker really the only alternative now?

Comment: What is filepicker? And who said it was an alternative? Have a look at MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.